# Powershell: join two lines in a array

Tags: powershell

I got a array which has the value(new line after every "text")

```
$result=@"
        "first","line","of","text"
        "second","line","of","text
        third","line","of","text"
        "fourth","line","of","text"
       "@
```

I am trying to write a powershell code which searches for lines that start with " but does not end with ". If it matches the condition next line is joined to the matched line with a comma delimiter. Ex: second line matches the condition, so third line is joined with the second line with a comma in between. like the one below

```
"first","line","of","text"
"second","line","of","text,third","line","of","text"
"fourth","line","of","text"
```

So far I have this with me. But it only adds a , to EOL but does not join it. Please let me know what am I missing

```
$result=@()
foreach ($item in $result){
if ($item -notlike '*"') 
{ $result+=$item+"," } 
else
{ $result+=$item}
}
```

Comment: Hm, this may be an x-y problem. Can you explain why you want to do that?

Comment: I am trying search lines that does not end with ". if it matches the case, then I need to join the matched line with next line (with a comma in between) to make it as single line.  And this variable result has multiple lines which does not end with "

I have highlighted the desired output in second code section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I got a array which has the value(new line after every "text")
>
> ```
> $result=@"
>         "first","line","of","text"
>         "second","line","of","text
>         third","line","of","text"
>         "fourth","line","of","text"
> "@
> ```
>
> <sub>* *(syntax error fixed)*</sub>

No, you have a multi-line string - there's a difference!

You can use a regular expression pattern to match linebreaks surrounded by optional whitespace, but no `"` characters:

```
$result = $result -replace '(?<!")\s*\r?\n\s*(?!")', ','
```

The pattern consists of:

- `(?<!")` - no preceding `"` (negative lookbehind assertion)
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace characters
- `\r?\n` - line break (`CRLF` or `LF`)
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace characters
- `(?!")` - no following `"` (negative lookahead assertion)

And finally replaces the thing with a `,`

Comment: Brilliant. Very good reminder of us of negative **lookahead** and **lookbehind** assertions in regular expressions

Comment: @clicks010 you're most welcome. Please consider accepting my answer if it solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark on the left

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a real **XY problem** but the question is fuzzy (confusion between a multi-line string and an array for example). Solution from Mathias is fine. However I think the original poster, according to the expected result, missed the correct syntax for the @""@ **Here** string which is ***very verbatim***: all leading spaces were **not** intentional. Hence this:

```
$result=@"
"first","line","of","text"
"second","line","of","text
third","line","of","text"
"fourth","line","of","text"
"@
$result=$result -replace '(?<!")\r?\n(?!")', ','
write-output $result
```

which brings this:

```
"first","line","of","text"
"second","line","of","text,third","line","of","text"
"fourth","line","of","text"
```

Answer (score 0):

with multiple replace

```
$result=@"
"first","line","of","text"
"second","line","of","text
third","line","of","text"
"fourth","line","of","text"
"@

(((($result -split "`n") -join """ ") -replace """ """, """`n""") -replace """ ", " ") -replace "\""`n", "`n"
```